# Create a binary wall

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, binary

Given an array of positive integers in base 10, where `n > 0`, output their representation of a binary wall.

**How does this work?**

1. Convert each number to its binary representation.
2. Pad the representation with leading zeroes to the length of the longest one i.e. `1, 2` -> `1, 10` -> `01, 10`.
3. Create a wall where the `1`s are bricks and `0`s are missing bricks.

A wall is a block of characters where any printable character represents a brick and a space (ASCII decimal code `32`) represents a missing brick. You may choose any character for the brick, it need not be distinct across the wall as long as it isn't a white space character. The missing brick character must be a space. For the example below I have used `*` for the bricks.

**Example**

Input:

```
[ 15, 7, 13, 11 ]
```

1. `[ 1111, 111, 1101, 1011 ]`
2. `[ 1111, 0111, 1101, 1011 ]`
3. Output:

   ```
   ****
    ***
   ** *
   * **
   ```

**Rules**

- Input must be taken in base 10, if your language accepts other bases you may not use them.
- Leading and trailing new lines are allowed.
- Input may be taken as a list of integers, separate arguments or any reasonable format.
- Output may be in any reasonable format: new line separated string, array of lines, 2d array etc.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are disallowed.

**Test Cases**

Note that in the first test case all of layers have an empty brick at the end.

```
[ 14, 4, 6, 2 ]

*** 
 *  
 ** 
  * 

[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ]

    *
   * 
  *  
 *   
*

[ 15, 11, 15, 15 ]

****
* **
****
****

[ 11, 10, 9, 8 ]

* **
* * 
*  *
*
```

This is code golf so shortest code wins!

Comment: Can the output be an array of lines or a 2d array of chars?

Comment: @ovs Sorry thought I'd specified that, yes you can output an array or 2d array etc. Any reasonable format.

Comment: In the case of a 2D array, can we use numbers for the bricks instead of characters? e.g. `[[1, " ", 1, " "], ...]`

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah that seems fine.

Comment: trailing whitespace is allowed?

Comment: @Giuseppe New lines only, otherwise it will be confused for empty bricks.

Comment: `may not`, not `cannot` :P

Comment: What's with the rule about base 10? It's all an int internally anyway, regardless if you parse the number in base 10 or base 2 or base 16… What's the point of this rule?

Comment: @therealfarfetchd One of the steps is to convert to base 2, it would be pretty pointless if you already took input in base 2...

Comment: What would be different with for example in Java: Integer.parseInt("14", 10) and Integer.parseInt("E", 16)? They all yield int(14). But now I'm thinking you're thinking of not parsing the number at all, in which case, the rule makes sense. But then, again, when not parsing the number you don't have "an array of positive integers", but an array of strings. That probably just threw me off. I think I get it now though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
B42*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38nESCv5//9oQ0MdBUMDHQVLHQWLWAA)

#### Explanation

```
B     % Implicitly input an array of numbers. Convert to binary. 
      % Gives a matrix with each row corresponding to a number
42    % Push 42 (ASCII code of '*')
*     % Multiply
c     % Convert to char. Char 0 is displayed as space. Implicitly display
```

Comment: *You may choose any character for the brick, it need not be distinct across the wall as long as it isn't a white space character.* yeah that means you probably don't need `42*` or something...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I could choose any other number, but I do need those three bytes I think.

Comment: What if there's a 1-byte builtin for `100` or some other number?

Answer (score 13):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
' *'{~#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYnLCYAwFMDunSIgWPXk07Z@ii4jFvHiAIKr175LSMidc2JbsXT2/arVmPO4HpqY2npHPBMyIkJEHI7AoFromJGg4fUrvVbRnoU55x8)

### Explanation

```
' *'{~#:  Input: array of integers
      #:  Convert each to binary with left-padding
' *'{~    Use the digits to index into the string ' *'
```

Comment: Oh, so `#:` is why this beats Jelly.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Bo⁶Uz⁶ZUY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98p/1HjttAqIBEVGvn///9oQ1MdBXMdBUNjIDaMBQA)

EDIT: HOW J BEAT JELLY DAT IMPOSSIBLE >_<

Answer (score 9):

## Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(x)[dec2bin(x)-16,'']
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzOiU12SgpMw/I1DU001FXj/2fphFtaGptbm1obG1oGKv5HwA)

**Explanation:**

Saved some bytes thanks to Luis Mendo! Also, I didn't notice that I could choose which character to build the wall with, not only `*`.

```
@(x)                    % Take the input as a column vector
    dec2bin(x)          % Convert each row of the input to a string with 1 and 0
                        % It gets automatically padded with zeros, to fit the longest number
    dec2bin(x)-16       % Subtract 16, to get from the ASCII-values of 1/0 (48/49)
                        % to 32/33 (space and !)
@(x)[dec2bin(x)-16,'']  % Concatenate with the empty string to convert it to a string.
```

---

Or with `de2bi`:

**Explanation:**

```
@(x)                          % Take the input as a column vector
               de2bi(x)       % Convert each row of the input to a binary number.
                              % Gets automatically padded to fit the longest number
            42*de2bi(x)       % Multiply the matrix by 42, which is the ASCII-value for *
           [42*de2bi(x),'']   % Concatenate the matrix with the empty string to convert
                              % it to a string. 0 are automatically displayed as spaces
@(x)fliplr([42*de2bi(x),''])
```

---

The following works on TIO, for 7 bytes more:

```
@(x)fliplr([42*(dec2bin(x)>48),''])
```

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0Iz2sRISyMlNdkoKTMPyLUzsdDUUVeP/Z@mEW1oam1ubWhsbWgYq/kfAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>88 84 71 74</s> 72 bytes

A lambda that returns a list of Strings, representing each line.

```python
lambda n:[bin(x)[2:].replace(*'0 ').rjust(len(bin(max(n)))-2)for x in n]
```

[Try it online! (link to the newline separated version)](https://tio.run/##jctBDoIwEIXhvaeYsOmMqQRQjJJwEsqiSIkQGEitST19LXsXLl7e5vu3j3uufA5DrcKsl67XwFXTjYyemqJqU2u2WT8MHkUGglI7vV8OZ8O4m0V7ZCI6FTSsFjyMDNyGzY7sUCgW6bRGNmCTlxLyPG7/siWShvs6Uaw4ocOvYMeZhLuE2x8cIi8kXKKO3RViQuEL)

### Explanation

- `lambda n:` - Creates an (anonymous) lambda, with a parameter `n`. Returns implicitly.
- `[...]` - Creates a list comprehension.
- `bin(x)[2:]` - Gets the binary representations of the numbers.
- `.replace(*'0 ')` - Replaces all the occurrences of `0` with a space.
- `.rjust(len(bin(max(n)))-2)` - Pads the binary representations to the length of the longest one.
- `for x in n` - Iterates through `n`, with the variable `x`.

---

#### Changelog

- *-<s>1</s> - 3 bytes thanks to @Rod, `-(...)+2` = `2-(...)`, use of `rjust()`*
- <s>Added a version with `bin()` instead, that was invalid since it didn't work for `1` and `2`.</s>
- <s>Fixed the bug above using `format()`.</s>
- Changed return type to list of Strings, because it was allowed by the OP.
- Fixed yet another bug using `rjust()` and switching back to `bin()`, spotted and fixed by @Rod.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes by using numbers instead of characters for the bricks, as suggested by Rick Hitchcock*

Returns a 2D array with 1's for the bricks.

```js
f=(a,b=[],x=1)=>a.every(n=>n<x)?a.map(n=>b.map(i=>n&i?1:' ')):f(a,[x,...b],x*2)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(a,b=[],x=1)=>a.every(n=>n<x)?a.map(n=>b.map(i=>n&i?1:' ')):f(a,[x,...b],x*2)

format = a => a.map(s => s.join``).join`\n`

console.log(format(f([ 14, 4, 6, 2 ])))
console.log(format(f([ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ])))
console.log(format(f([ 15, 11, 15, 15 ])))
console.log(format(f([ 11, 10, 9, 8 ])))
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>63</s> 59 bytes

-4 bytes with help from Alexis Andersen

```
->*n{puts n.map{|i|("%#{('%b'%n.max).size}b"%i).tr'0',' '}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104rr7qgtKRYIU8vN7GguiazRkNJVblaQ101SV0VJFahqVecWZVam6SkmqmpV1KkbqCuo66gXlv7Py3a0FRHwVxHwdAYiA1j/wMA)

Comment: you don't need the 0 in the string format. you could shave a byte by replacing `n.max.to_s(2).size` with `('%b'%n.max).size` and you don't actually need to replace the `1` with `*`

Comment: @AlexisAndersen thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
bí.Bí»0ð‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/6fBaPafDaw/tNji84VHDwv//ow1NdRTMdRQMjYHYMBYA)

Comment: Beat me by 38 seconds. I had `b0ð:í.Bí»` for 9 bytes as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```hs
f x|all(<1)x=x>>[""]|a<-f$map(`div`2)x=zipWith(++)a$map(cycle[" ","*"]!!)x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoiYxJ0fDxlCzwrbCzi5aSSm2JtFGN00lN7FAIyElsyzBCChTlVkQnlmSoaGtrZkIlkmuTM5JjVZSUNJR0lKKVVTUrPifm5iZZ1tQWhJcUqRSmpeTmZdarJIWrWBoqqNgrqNgaAzEhgqx/wE)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 87 <s>88</s> bytes

Wall blocks represented by an `8`, because, well lots of eights.

```r
write(ifelse((I=sapply(scan(),intToBits))[(M=max(which(I>0,T)[,1])):1,],8,' '),1,M,,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwEAXAq6TLLrzC7VTQws7CLp1YBIm44A8TUE8fZ@6cn1tTIF3CFgNR30R/XdtHcfYHMfRI7uw0ReaRhmb3Lz2rziv1bQHHI2RirgUTSlhjGYIBsJaziJHCVKbMPw)

Input integer list is converted to array of bits which are trimmed of trailing 0 bits and reversed.

The reduced array is then output using `write` and a column width which was determined when the array was trimmed.

`ifelse()` is the only IF option that works on vectors unfortunately.

Comment: @Vlo pointed out you can use `1` rather than `""` for the output file in `write`.

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>30</s> <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Adám*

```apl
' *'[⍉2⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862h3/qytoqUc/6u00etS19FHv4kPrDR91LQKqif0PlP7vyKVhaKpgrmBorGBoqMkFFAfqVFfnAombKJgomCkYoYkqGAGFLRQMzdDETYEGKIBIUzQJoKiBgqWChSYA)

(assumes `⎕IO←0` as this is default on many machines)

This takes input as an array and returns a matrix with `*`s and  s.

#### Explanation

```apl
2⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕       Convert input to binary (returns a transposed matrix of 1s and 0s)
⍉              Transpose
' *'[ ... ]    Index into this string
```

Comment: Save 6 bytes with [`' *'[⍉2⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕]`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862h3/qytoqUc/6u00etS19FHv4kPrDR91LQKqif0PlP7vyKVhaKpgrmBorGBoqMkFFAfqVFfnAombKJgomCkYoYkqGAGFLRQMzdDETYEGKIBIUzQJoKiBgqWChSYA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Thanks for the tips, I didn't know I could remove the `¨`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```python
lambda k:[[' *'[i>>y&1]for y in range(len(bin(max(k)))-3,-1,-1)]for i in k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BDoIwEEX3nOKvpDUlsahESeAitYsSQRugEOhCTl/bGkkmmXlvfvLnzb4nk7uuerhBjc1ToS@FSHFMha7r7cBlNy3YoA0WZV4tGVpDGm3IqD6kp5RmZ5ZxPzQGdQj20tl2tSsqiAQQ4BcGPwVDDsl@yt9R3hh4sdurJ/@K@7rbYE4Md5@GTGQSmkJDKItNpc/NizY24g4dCUj/7L4)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 100 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{if(($c=($a=[convert]::ToString($_,2)).length)-gt$l){$l=$c}$a-replace0,' '}|%{$_.padleft($l)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoMwEADAr/SwxQRUWpEehLyivRWRkK5RWJIQl/Zg8/bV@zAp/jBvCxKJgM1@@1/3dVYKnFFgzdvF8MXM4zC84pPzGryCqe60bgmD50U3noH0DmTAFbBNxkTW4a2uLlU5M5jaZD@EM6vTFRG599LLQ7oD)

Ugh, `convert`ing to binary in PowerShell is so painful. Plus `.length`y calls to `-replace` the `0` with spaces, plus a long `.padLeft()` call to make them all the same `.length`, all adds up to a long submission.

Golfing suggestions to get below 100 are welcome.

Comment: using:
 - `|% Le*` instead of `.length`
 - `|% *ce 0 ' '` instead of `-replace0,' '`
 - `|% *ft $l`instead of `.padleft($l)`

 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCsIwFAXQX3nDLU2KghZ1KOQP3HQTKSG8xkJoJA06tPn2Z13PcN7xy2l@cQgisMnPa7WMg1JwRsGah4vTh1N@dt093nIaJ6/Q71qt14qu3Oi9zwh6QTBwBXbTxjEdqKa6bBX6vwyZEIqIHM9ykou0Pw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 290 bytes

```
declare @ int;select @=max(log(a,2))+1from @i;with t as(select convert(varchar(max),a%2)b,a/2c,@-1m,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by(select 1))r from @i union all select convert(varchar(max),concat(c%2,b))b,c/2c,m-1,r from t where m>0)select replace(b,0,' ')from t where m=0group by r,b order by r
```

Uses `1` for the brick piece, assumes input comes from table `@`

Ungolfed, with some explanation

```
-- assume input is presented in an input table
declare @input table (a int)
insert into @input values (15), (7), (13), (11)

---- start here

-- figure out how many characters are needed, by taking log2
declare @max int
select @max = max(log(a, 2)) + 1
from @input

-- recursive cte
-- will join against itself, recursively finding each digit in the binary string
;with cte as
(
    select 
        convert(varchar(max), a % 2) as b, -- is the least significant bit 1 or 0
        a / 2 as c, -- remove least significant bit, for the next run
        @max - 1 as max, -- keep track of iterations left
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) as rn -- keep the order of the input
    from @input

    union all -- recursive loop
              -- below columns follow the same pattern

    select convert(varchar(max), 
        concat(cte.c % 2, cte.b)) as b, -- prepend the current binary string with the newest least significant bit
        cte.c / 2 as c, 
        cte.max - 1, 
        cte.rn
    from cte
    where cte.max > 0
)
select replace(b, 0, ' ') -- swap 0s for space
from cte
where max = 0 -- only take the last iteration
group by rn, b -- grab each unique input, 
               -- need to group by row number so it can be ordered by
               -- need to group by binary string, so it can be selected
order by rn -- sort by the order the input arrived in
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
Grid@PadLeft@IntegerDigits[#,2]/. 0->""&
```

Bricks are 1s

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
Grid@PadLeft@IntegerDigits[#,2]/.{0->"",1->"#"}&
```

Bricks are #

Comment: You should only need one slash in the `//.`. (`/.` means "replace once", `//.` means "keep doing the replacement until the thing stops changing".)

Comment: You don't need the space after the comma in the IntegerDigits function.

Comment: yes,I know,this happens when you copy/paste from notebook.fixed

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 84 bytes

```php
while(++$i<$argc)echo strtr(sprintf("\n%".-~log(max($argv),2).b,$argv[$i]),10,"* ");
```

Luckily, the bit operation casts the `log` result to int. float wouldn´t work here.

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a51cbe200ffc13107212f264a8520b3501ef05c1).

Comment: `error_reporting(~E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` is better, and php8 can't work, maybe should add version in title.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>112+18=130</strike> 86+41=127 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Select(n=>C.ToString(n,2).Replace("0"," ").PadLeft(C.ToString(a.Max(),2).Length))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZBPawIxEMXv@ymGPW0gDa79j@4eKm1pqyBa8GA9pHHcBnYTm0RbET/7NuuK9VCKh9KB5PB4M795I@yJ0AbLhZUqg@HKOixYV6r3Vq10kp3W0WqJxrWCQPEC7ZwLhBupuFmNeJ4H6wB8iZxbC32jM8OLrVLrVVnHnRSw1HIKPS5VZJ3xhPEEuMks2fu@O6ra0e8WSrSlcuMJhf1CeY7CSa0su0eFRgr2cKsWBRr@mmO7Hp@mMIMkKHmScjbEqiNSSdphz3q4NUSKNgkb4Dz3iaKwEdIQQsL6fNrFmYsOjJz1@GdEKnsXVebeCCn9OX7Y1t/K6hzZyEiH/pi4y8oetc8dvqiQwixS@OHDryE@p3BJIT71L4YNIaR13NBjfb/CKTQpnFG48vSLf6d7fNygcO35f8ceIJ8@4erQtQnqfxOUXw)

The byte count includes 41 bytes from `using System.Linq;using C=System.Convert;`. Uses `1` as character for the wall. Nonetheless, this is way too long even for C#...

Comment: Place in `namespace System.Linq{}` to save some bytes. Is `a.Max()` guaranteed to be true (I'm sure it is I'm just not the smartest with binary :P)? Would `class Convert{}` save any bytes?

Comment: If I place the program in a given namespace, shouldn't I submit the whole program instead of just a lambda? I'm not sure about the rules for that...

Comment: I've usually just placed in namespace with lambda. I don't think there's ever been a question about it and it is in the C# tips page.

Comment: I don't think this is valid, as you can't compile it without using static imports.

Comment: @MetaColon you can check the whole code in the TIO link, see that it does not use static imports, but an alias for a certain type.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo actually I meant alias using directives.

Comment: @MetaColon that's the reason why I added the bytes in `using System.Linq;using C=System.Convert;` to byte count, as those two `using` directives are needed for the code to compile.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I think saving `Convert.ToString(int, int)` to a lambda might make this shorter. e.g. `var b = (int n) => System.Convert.ToString(n, 2);`, making the `using` unnecassry and letting you do: `a=>a.Select(n=>b(n).Replace("0"," ").PadLeft(b(a.Max(),2).Length))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 63 bytes

```
.+
$*#<
+`(#+)\1
$1 
 #
#
{T`<`_`^(<.+(¶|$))+$
m`^<
 <
(.)<
<$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRUvZhks7QUNZWzPGkEvFUIFLQZlLmas6JMEmIT4hTsNGT1vj0LYaFU1NbRWu3IQ4Gy4FGy4NPU0bLhsVw///DU24TLjMuIwA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*#<
```

Convert to unary, and suffix a `<`.

```
+`(#+)\1
$1 
 #
#
```

Convert to binary.

```
{T`<`_`^(<.+(¶|$))+$
```

Once all the `<`s have reached the left, delete them all.

```
m`^<
 <
```

Insert a space before any `<`s that have already reached the left.

```
(.)<
<$1
```

Move all the `<`s left one step. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```
¡'0p(¡X¤lÃn o)-X¤l)+X¤)£" *"gX
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=oScwcCihWKRsw24gbyktWKRsKStYpCmjIiAqImdY&input=WzE0LDQsNiwyXS1S)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@Justin Mariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner)

#### Explanation

```
¡                              // map input integers
    (¡X¤lÃn o)                 // longest binary string length
              -X¤l)            // minus current binary string length
 '0p                           // repeat zero
                   +X¤)        // concat with current binary string
                       £       // map chars of binary string
                        " *"gX // swap 0 and 1 with ' ' and '*'
```

Comment: You can drop the last 3 chars to just return an array of strings, and use the `-R` flag (not added to byte count) to see the newline-joined output: [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=oScwcCihWKRsw24gbyktWKRsKStYpCmjIiAqImdY&input=WzE0LDQsNiwyXQotUg==).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>92</strike> 90 bytes

```python
lambda a:[' '*(len(bin(max(a)))-len(i)-2)+i for i in[bin(i)[2:].replace(*'0 ')for i in a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEAV/5d2yq6loFA8FvyTksNUEF9I0hB7062N7EOY0DFO/63sp197TI8s8vQQyegNzoBwLTVpolg8JMw@7UB4cHxVpaVBo8Xuh7N0YTi3WLM9I5mzsduB/Awmh16ZlpUQel5vFxt3CITD3Hw)

Returns a list of lines. Stacking them up shows they do indeed align properly.

```python
['111 ', ' 1  ', ' 11 ', '  1 ']
>>>
 111 
  1  
  11 
   1
```

## The breakdown

Essentially converts the array to binary, then replaces all 0's with spaces. `N` number of spaces are added to the front of each line where `N = [length of longest line] - [length of line]`.

`-1 bytes` Thanks to Mr. Xoder

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCsIwEEbhq/y7zNRWNIqLQk8Ss5hqggNpGkIXevpoF8JbPb7y2V5rvrQ43VuSZX4KZHQGpqMUMs2aaZE3CTMP@1AeLB8Uca1QaHa7UHZ29McaSpJHoM6cYPgvIN63UjVvFMnhfO3x69bDwjO3Lw)

Comment: You can't have leading or trailing spaces in the output.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Oh, must have misread the rules! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcpBCsIwEEbhq/y7zNRWNIqLQk8Ss5hqggNpGkIXevpoF8JbPb7y2V5rvrQ43VuSZX4KZHQGpqMUMs2aaZE3CTMP@1AeLB8Uca1QaHa7UHZ29McaSpJHoM6cYPgvIN63UjVvFMnhfO3x69bDwjO3Lw), replace `'0',' '` with `*'0 '`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah interesting, would never have thought about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 185 bytes

```
(fn[i](let[b(map #(Long/toBinaryString %)i)](map #(clojure.string/replace(clojure.string/replace(format(str"%0"(reduce(fn[l i](max l(count i)))0 b)"d")(read-string %))"1""#")"0"" ")b)))
```

### Ungolfed version:

```
(fn [i]
    (let [b (map #(Long/toBinaryString %) i)]
        (map
            #(clojure.string/replace
                (clojure.string/replace
                    (format
                        (str "%0"
                            (reduce
                                (fn [l i] (max l(count i))) 0 b)
                            "d")
                        (read-string %))
                        "1"
                        "#")
                "0"
                " ")
        b)))
```

Anonymous function that takes the argument as a list. Returns the lines as list.

Reading the other answers, I bet it could be smaller. `clojure.string/replace` takes an obscene amount of chars to write..

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>130</s> <s>108</s> 88 bytes

Saved 22 thanks to @TheLethalCoder
Saved 20 thanks to @Xanderhall

```java
void a(int[]b){for(int i:b)System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(i).replace('0',' '));}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
void a(int[]b){
    for(int i:b)
        System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(i).replace('0', ' '));       
}
```

Comment: Post increment `i` at `b[i]` to save a byte. You can keep the output with `1`'s so no need for the `.replace('1','*')`. Use Java 8 instead and compile to a lambda to save bytes. If you don't want to do that `int[]b` saves a byte.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain what "Post increment i at b[i] to save a byte." means?

Comment: `i++` evaluates `i` then increments it (whereas `++i` does the opposite) so you can move the `i++` out of the `for` loop and use `b[i++]` instead. Oh and whilst we're at it you only have one line inside your loop so the braces aren't needed.

Comment: True! Amazing, thank you

Comment: You can save a few bytes by switching your loop to a foreach loop. `for(int x:i)` Also, you can use `Long.toBinaryString` instead of the Integer version to save 3 bytes.

Comment: Great Xanderhall! Thank you :)

Comment: Might want to actually make `Java 7` link to something.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
m¤z3 z ·r0S
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=baR6MyB6ILdyMFM=&inputs=WzE0LCA0LCA2LCAyXQ==,WzEsIDIsIDQsIDgsIDE2XQ==,WzE1LCAxMSwgMTUsIDE1XQ==,WzExLCAxMCwgOSwgOF0=)

### Explanation

```
m¤z3 z ·r0S  Implicit input of array
m¤           Map the array to binary strings
  z3 z       Rotate right 270° and then right 90°. This adds left padding to each string
       ·r0S  Join with newlines and replace 0s with spaces
```

Comment: Nice exploit with `z3 z`. Not sure why `y y` doesn't work there, I'll look into it later...

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 98 bytes

```powershell
$p=$args|%{$n=$_;31..0|?{($n-shr$_)%2}}|sort
$args|%{$n=$_;-join($p[-1]..0|%{' *'[($n-shr$_)%2]})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHxaoMwEMb/z1McIc4kxFLb2W0MWd@jFBlbtnaIOuPYQPPs7pKo2JDjSy73y3dwTf2rW3PRZTmyD8ihH1mTs9f20wxRz6qcFc/7dLPZDi89Z1ViLi0rRLSzdjB125HbyuSrvlacNackPTsm6mOQ8WkNnq2woyXkyAlRnKeZggcF6R4jFYqTWOKKFUEwqJQQFBMxEcJT9wpwHxTsZgYCA5NOd0wsDBZ76hGtDh4DXMHLF07A8hMEW3eY/8hcmxhOs5t2fXtqdZerdh2yVfCE5gGCBZpN5GzmISJggAh64txZeTWdYvqv0W@dfschsSI8tNr8lB0m7nB2R1fm85RxOr3RRH/TBaWCrkFix38)

The script uses the fact that an integer contains no more than 32 bits.

The first line calculates positions of the bits with 1. The second line renders a binary wall.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
j_MC.tm_X.Bd\0\
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_MC.tm_X.Bd%5C0%5C+&input=%5B15%2C+7%2C+13%2C+11%5D&debug=0) Mind the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 217 bytes

After 2 hours of coding i decided, that numpy is bad idea for this

```py
import numpy as n
i=n.loadtxt("i")
o=[n.copy(i)]
o[0].fill(10)
while n.count_nonzero(i)>0:
 o.append(i%2+32)
 i=n.vectorize(lambda x:x//2)(i)
print n.fliplr(n.array(o).T).astype('uint8').view('c').tostring().decode()
```

### Usage in Ubuntu

Install numpy

```py
python2 -m pip install numpy
```

Create file named `i` with input in format `14 4 6 2`

Run

```py
python2 prog.py
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>170</s></sub> 161 Bytes

#### Golfed

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that that takes input of format `1 2 3 .. n` from range `[A1]` and outputs the corresponding binary wall to the VBE Immediate window via range `[B1,C1,2:2]`

```vb
n=Split([A1]):[A2].Resize(1,UBound(n)+1)=n:[C1]="=Int(1+Log(B1,2))":For Each i In n:[B1]=i:?Replace(Replace([Right(Rept(0,C1)&Dec2Bin(B1),C1)],1,"*"),0," "):Next
```

Formatted:

```vb
n=Split([A1])
[A2].Resize(1,UBound(n)+1)=n
[C1]="=Int(1+Log(B1,2))"
For Each i In n
[B1]=i
?Replace(Replace([Right(Rept(0,C1)&Dec2Bin(B1),C1)],1,"*"),0," ")
Next
```

#### Ungolfed

Full `Sub`routine that takes input of format `Array(1, 2, 3...)` and outputs the corresponding binary wall to the VBE Immediate window via range `[A1,B1,2:2]`

```vb
Sub a(ByRef n As Variant)
    Let Range("A1").Resize(1,UBound(n)+1) = n
    Let Range("C1").Value = "=Int(1+Log(A1,2))"
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each i In n
        Let Range("A1").Value = i
        Debug.Print Replace(
                            Replace(
                                    [Right( Rept( 0, C1) & Dec2Bin( B1), C1)],
                                    1,
                                    "*"
                            ),
                            0,
                            " "
                    )
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>232</s> <s>254</s> 250 bytes

**Code**

```
0 >r a:new swap ( nip 2 base drop >s decimal s:len r> n:max >r a:push ) a:each drop a:new swap ( nip '0 G:c# r@ G:#> s:fmt a:push ) a:each drop rdrop a:new swap ( nip /0/ " " s:replace! a:push ) a:each drop ( nip /1/ "*" s:replace! . cr ) a:each drop
```

**Ungolfed version with comments**

```
\ convert to binary and save longest string length
: f 0 >r a:new swap ( nip 2 base drop >s decimal s:len r> n:max >r a:push ) a:each drop ;

\ pad binary number with zero
: f1 a:new swap ( nip '0 G:c# r@ G:#> s:fmt a:push ) a:each drop rdrop ;

\ replace every 0 with space
: f2 a:new swap ( nip /0/ " " s:replace! a:push ) a:each drop ;

\ replace every 1 with * and print each line of bricks
: f3 ( nip /1/ "*" s:replace! . cr ) a:each drop ;
```

These words must be invoked in sequence (see example)

**Usage and examples**

```
ok> [15,7,13,11] 0 >r a:new swap ( nip 2 base drop >s decimal s:len r> n:max >r a:push ) a:each drop a:new swap ( nip '0 G:c# r@ G:#> s:fmt a:push ) a:each drop rdrop a:new swap ( nip /0/ " " s:replace! a:push ) a:each drop ( nip /1/ "*" s:replace! . cr ) a:each drop
****
 ***
** *
* **
```

Or more clearly

```
ok> [15,11,15,15] f f1 f2 f3
****
* **
****
****
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
ＷＳ«⸿≔ＩιιＷι«←§ *ι≧÷²ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU1OhmoszAMgu0VCKKVLStObidCwuzkzP03BOLC7RyNTUUcgECUL1ZoLVQzVY@aSmlegoOJZ45qWkVmgoKWgpgVSDlHP6JhZAzAnKTM8oAdpZ4pJZlpmSqqNgBDWxlqv2/39DEy4TLjMuI67/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by manually converting each input number to binary but printing it in right-to-left order. I take the input as a newline terminated string as Charcoal doesn't have a good way of inputting lists otherwise I would write something like this which unfortunately currently takes 21 bytes:

```
ＷＳ⊞υＩιＷ⌈υ«Ｅυ﹪κ²↓⸿≧÷²υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc0xC4MwEIbhufkVwSmBdKhIh3YqunQQpF27BBVzNCZicloo/e3pCa7fPS/XGj23XtuUVgO25@LuJozPOIMbhJS8wWAEKl7qEAVIeWW7q/UHRhwFEvqyQ0NBpHHacO07tF68Fc/lluzXS@VXp3j2mrNtJHwLAQb3gMFEehwrWKDrqVIcSfxSOhWsYGeWs3Rc7B8) Link is to verbose version of code. This version vectorises over the input array, although its output is hardcoded to `-`s which saves a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs an array of lines, using `1` for the bricks

```
®¤r0SÃù
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rqRyMFPD%2bQ&footer=rmQiMSo&input=WzE1IDcgMTMgMTFdCi1S) (footer replaces `1`s with `*`s) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rqRyMFPD%2bQ&footer=UmlVrmQiMSoiw3VXZ1YguOctIFdnViC4ILc&input=WwpbMTUgNyAxMyAxMV0KWzE0IDQgNiAyXQpbMSAyIDQgOCAxNl0KWzE1IDExIDE1IDE1XQpbMTEgMTAgOSA4XQpdLW1S)

```
®¤r0SÃù     :Implicit input of array
®           :Map
 ¤          :  To binary string
  r0        :  Replace 0s with
    S       :  Space
     Ã      :End map
      ù     :Left pad each with spaces to the length of the longest
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
" *"@+2\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NSklBS8lB2yjmf5q6hqGpgrmCobGCoaG1oYmCiYKZgpG1oYIRkGWhYGhmDZQ2NFQAkabWIIaBgqWCheZ/AA)

Takes input as a list of integers, outputs as a list of strings.

- `2\` convert (implicit input) to base-2 representation
- `+` transpose result
- `" *"@` replace 0's with   and 1's with `*`

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｈ２┬！0∙ ╋∔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjI4JXVGRjEyJXUyNTJDJXVGRjAxMCV1MjIxOSUyMCV1MjU0QiV1MjIxNA__,i=JTVCMTQlMkM0JTJDNiUyQzIlNUQ_,v=8)

Uses 1 as the display character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=max -a`, 64 bytes

```perl
say$"x((length max@F)-y///c),y/0/ /r for@F=map{sprintf"%b",$_}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCsIgGADgVxFZsMHsV0KCwcCTpzp2DoutBKeiHpTo1fvb6Tt9cUlOImbTOlr73i3@Vd5kM1XpgTUAeA5jAw4EEllDUnreTPzkmKwvKz086Njdv0ojCknORJyIEL8Qiw0@I7vKIxd892JzmaZbsW7vFZn5Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
bvṅ0ðvVøɽ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJiduG5hTDDsHZWw7jJvSIsIiIsIlsxNSwgNywgMTMsIDExXSJd)

### How?

```
bvṅ0ðvVøɽ
b         # Get the binary representation of each as a list
 vṅ       # Join each by nothing to make them a string
   0ðvV   # Replace all zeros with a space
       øɽ # Prepend leading spaces to each to align it to the right
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 9 bytes

```
⊏:" *"≡⇌⋯
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oqPOiIgKiLiiaHih4zii68KCkYgWzE0IDQgNiAyXQpGIFsxIDIgNCA4IDE2XQpGIFsxNSAxMSAxNSAxNV0KRiBbMTEgMTAgOSA4XQo=)

```
⊏:" *"≡⇌⋯
        ⋯  # convert to bits
      ≡⇌   # reverse each row
⊏:" *"     # convert to characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 14 bytes

```
Z RZJ R*TBgR0s
```

Uses `1` as the brick character. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7IKlpSVpuhbrohSCorwUgrRCnNKDDIohglC5jdGGhjoKhgY6CpY6ChY6CuYwTQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
Z RZJ R*TBgR0s
          g    ; List of command-line args
        TB     ; Convert to binary
           R0s ; Replace 0 with space
      R*       ; Reverse each
   ZJ          ; Transpose, filling missing spots with spaces
  R            ; Reverse
Z              ; Transpose again
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>x.some(t=>t)?f(x.map(t=>t>>1)).map((t,i)=>t+(x[i]&1||' ')):x.fill``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fczBCsIwDAbgu0@Rk2uwFic6VGh9kCm06CodXSuuSA9791oreNMQCH/4kl491Xh5mHtYOn/tUtI8chHZ6IeOBC4CHjWJbFD3koSoEUsigRrMmwWJrTnP62mqoEI8RKaNtVIm7R@DCsBBARegWO@NkycnF9XJ8W9Vs9nFu9Hbjll/I58jokkL9YZC7obCGs6I@NNlUOSOQt38p9tMsi9z@5@@2YrCPv8tML0A)